# Character ' getting encoded to ��� in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, encoding, utf-8, http-headers

The desired response that I need to return from my API is (I’m) but instead of this I am getting I���m.
Basically ' is getting encoded as ���.
The response of the API is coming from a JSON file.
When I run the API on my localhost it is giving desired response, but on an open-shift cluster where it is deployed I am getting ���.

To be clear:

- My desired output is **`I’m`**
- My actual output is **`I���m`**

In my Spring Boot Application, for this API I have made the HTTP Headers as

```
httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

but still the encoding is not resolved.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps you should post your intended result.

Comment: I want the response should have (I'm using this ) instead of (I���m using this)

Comment: Maybe your _apostrophe_ is `‘` (U+2018,  *Left Single Quotation Mark*), UTF-8 byte sequence `'\xe2\x80\x98'`?

Comment: Regarding _"Basically ' is getting encoded as ���"_, that is definitely not the case. Instead, ' is getting _rendered_ as ���. Those black diamonds are [replacement characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), and are being shown because your output contains unrecognized characters which cannot be displayed. That in itself doesn't solve your problem at all, but it is essential for properly understanding it.

Comment: Did you really use that character? By the way, `I’m` in json would be `Iâ€™m`.